# Where is my python-flask app source stored on ec2 instance deployed with elastic beanstalk?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-linux

I just deployed a flask-python app with elastic beanstalk on AWS but cannot locate my app source files like application.py or templates/index.html etc

I've looked at looked at /var/../.. or /opt/../.. etc but nowhere to be found.

Is there an ebs command like $ eb find 'filename.py' etc?

Comment: How about `eb ssh` or `eb ssh --command`? See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-ssh.html

Comment: I already ssh in and looked at the directories /var/../.. or /opt/../.. etc but don't see any of my application source files

Answer (score 11):

- /opt/python – Root of where you application will end up.
- /opt/python/current/app – The current application that is hosted in the environment.
- /opt/python/on-deck/app – The app is initially put in on-deck and then, after all the deployment is complete, it will be moved to current. If you are getting failures in yourcontainer_commands, check out out the on-deck folder and not the current folder.
- /opt/python/current/env – All the env variables that eb will set up for you. If you are trying to reproduce an error, you may first need to source /opt/python/current/env to get things set up as they would be when eb deploy is running.
- opt/python/run/venv – The virtual env used by your application; you will also need to run source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate if you are trying to reproduce an error

Comment: Yes! Thank you. This is exactly the info I was looking for. Not sure if this is well documented anywhere, but it is super helpful. Would upvote 10 times if I could.

Answer (score 4):

As of today, using the default AWS Linux option when creating eb (Python 3.7 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.1.1), I found the application files in:

**/var/app/current**

If that doesn't work you can search for a file that you know to be unique in your app, e.g

```
sudo find / -name hello.html
```

In my case the above returns
**/var/app/current/templates/hello.html**